# c# как писать xPath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

Мне нужно использовать такой xPath `//*[@id="contact_methods"]/li[2]/div/strong`
но компилятор не принимает его из за двойных кавычек, побывал нечто такое `"//*[@id=" + "contact_methods" + "]/li[2]/div/strong"` но так локатор не работает корректно, как с этим быть?

Comment: XPath поддерживает одинарные кавычки, их вам и надо использовать.

Comment: весь локатор или "проблемную зону"?

Comment: Ну сами подумайте, XPath - это string, которое обозначается двойными кавычками, а само условие уже их содержат не должно. Так что должно быть что то вроде `"//div[@id='someId']"`.

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли

Comment: Напишите решение в ответ.

Comment: Помимо одинарных кавычек Вы должны знать, что двойные кавычки можно экранировать (ибо, я так понимаю, на данном этапе Вы вообще не можете записать в строку двойную кавычку). `"\""` или `@""""`

Answer (score 0):

```
"//*[@id='contact_methods']/li[2]/div/strong"
```